# Is it possible to grab listener through fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently I start testing not using interface for passing concrete listener from activity to fragments.

this code works:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //......Skip
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity(), year, month, day);
}
```

But when I do it same between fragments, it seem doesn't work.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...Skip
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), ((TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener)((newFragment)getParentFragment())) ,hour, minute,false);
}
```

I tested with log and the listener from parent fragment seem doesn't called.
I have also tried with getContext.

Am I passing wrong listener reference? thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing any crash/exception thrown (Like ClassCastException)? And why are you casting `getParentFragment()` to `newFragment` and then casting to `OnTimeSetListener`

Comment: newFragment is the parent frag name .I have already tried not to cast, but seems not work

Comment: well directly cast `getParentFragment()` to `OnTimeSetListener` ?

Comment: Do you get a crash/error log? *Edit:* It could also help to include the class where you call `onCreateDialog()`, including the import declarations.

Comment: I did error check and resulted getParentFrafment always return null,  I don't know why but curiously it works when I use setTargetFragment

Answer (score 1):

Try this : your fragment must implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener , DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

```
           DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    FragmentName.this, //pass fragment name 
                    Year,
                    Month,
                    Day
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//...Skip
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), ((TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener)getParentFragment()) ,hour, minute,false);
```

}

Make sure parent fragment has implemented TimpePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener

And yout listener object in TimePickerDialog is initialized with the ParentFragment instance  you are using.